# How to display emaiIds with hyperlink when using php-mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am display the contents of mysql table using php.
Based on the user inputs, I will do some querying and the results results will be stored in an array and displayed.
Now I have emilIds in the output, when I display the table in the webpage, I want to display with hyperlinks. 
How can I achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```
if($result2->num_rows > 0){
    echo '<table width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="db-table" boarder-collapse ="collapse">';
    echo '<tr><th>STUDENT_NAME</th><th>CLASS</th><th>ID_NUMBER</th><th>ADDRESS</th><th>CITY</th><th>STATE</th><th>ZIP</th><th>COUNTRY</th><th>PHONE</th><th>INSURANCE</th>
<th>EMAIL</th><th>MAILING_ADDRESS</th><th>JOINED_ON</th></tr>';

    while($rowz2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($rowz2 as $key=>$value){
            echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';
        }                                                                                                                     
        echo '</tr>';
   }
   echo "</table><br/>";


}

else{
    echo "<h2>No data based on the entered values</h2>";
}
```

Comment: `echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';` Sayy Whaat.

Comment: Could you supply a expected result? Do you want to have a link that opens your email program with the email address already in the To: field?

Comment: Please check the HTML docs. 
You can do it in your foreach loop
if($key=='email') echo '<td><a href="mailto:$value">'.$value.'</a></td>';
else echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';
Hope this helps.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable yes that is how I want it. thanks

Comment: @Sid then Julio's answer is for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment yet so i will post it here. Check if your database column is 'email' or 'EMAIL' because

```
if ($key == 'EMAIL')
```

is case sensitive and as such it will never pass the condition if column is 'email'. If for some reason you need a case insensitive string comparison use:

```
if (strcasecmp($key, 'EMAIL') === 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an a tag with mail:

```
echo '<td><a href="mailto:' . $value. '">' . $value .'</a></td>';
```

Assuming that `$value` content is an email address

Changes based the code you posted in your comments:

Apparently was a couple of nesting problems but I think what you wanted to say was...

```
echo "<table>";
while($rowz2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){ 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    foreach($rowz2 as $key=>$value){ 
        if($key=='EMAIL') { 
            echo '<td><a href="mailto:' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a></td>'; 
        } else { 
            echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>'; 
        } 
    }
    echo '</tr>'; 
}
echo "</table><br/>";
```

I can't say for sure if that would work as you expect but if a value is retrieved from DB with a field name "EMAIL" then it will be echoed inside a mailto: link.

So whether the field name is `EMAIL` or you used `SELECT this_field, that_field, the_email_field as EMAIL FROM your_table` it would bring a working mailto: link in your table.

Comment: Julio,I added this piece of code inside my foreach.. nut its not working. while($rowz2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
echo "<tr>";
foreach($rowz2 as $key=>$value){

 if($key=='EMAIL') {
echo '<td><a href="mailto:'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a></td>';
}

 else echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';

}
                                                                                                        
echo '</tr>';


echo "</table><br/>";

}